# I need to separate the API initialization in a general place, then the rest of pages use the same instance

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

We use this way to open a connection to Firebse.

```
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

But when we use this API inside multiple pages we use singleton like this.

```
@registerModule
abstract class FirebaseInjectableModule {
  @lazySingleton
  FirebaseAuth get firebaseAuth => FirebaseAuth.instance;
}
```

How Could i use this this way with getX. I need to separate the API initialization in a general place, then the rest of pages use the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this in your main method or use in **bindings**:

```
 Get.lazyPut<FirebaseAuth>(()=>FirebaseAuth.instance, fenix: true); // `fenix: true` is somewhat like singletons
```

And then on your pages:

```
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = Get.find();
```

To get the instance.